# What is a proper way to modify a list of DB Objects using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

## Question

Using the spring MVC model and without any ORM solution, how am I supposed to treat a large list of database objects without multiplying the database queries?

---

## Research tracks

### Track 1

- Step 1: `SELECT` the objects with the DAO and put them in a (big) `List` with a `RowMapper`.
- Step 2: deal with my objects within the associated service in Java.
- step 3: loop on the (n-big) `List` to do n simple `UPDATE` in the DB

Queries for n objects: **1 + n**

### Track 2

Write a SQL query in the DAO that directly updates all the corresponding objects without extracting them.

Queries for n objects: **1**

### Thoughts

As track 2 seems far more efficient, it also seems to straightly go against the Spring MVC model as my services will tend to empty and my DAO will tend to expand.

Maybe there is a generic way to do an `UPDATE` on a Java `List` of objects in a database without multiplying the queries?

---

## Simple case

Given this table:

```
+----+---------+------+
|           MY_OBJECT |
+----+---------+------+
| ID | BOOLEAN | DATE |
+----+---------+------+
|  0 |       0 | NULL |
|  1 |       1 | NULL |
|  2 |       0 | NULL |
|  3 |       1 | NULL |
|  4 |       1 | NULL |
+----+---------+------+
```

I have a `MyObjectDao` and a `MyObjectService`.

I'd like to set `DATE` to the `SYSDATE()` for all objects that have the boolean to `true`.

Should it be full DAO with a query or should the DAO retrieve the objects, the service edit them and then the DAO update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some researches and put a lot of thoughts into this question. What I deduced from my work is that in the majority of cases the process should be:

- Pull the data from the DB with the DAO in a generic way
- Edit the objects the way you need it with the service / business layer
- Transmit the objects to the DAO to do a generic **batchUpdate**

The key element I was missing is the **batchUpdate**. Without it, updating a big `List` of elements would take minutes which is unacceptable. The big difference is not the amount of queries executed but how they are transmitted to the DB, avoiding multiple usages of the network layer in the batch update case.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that would typically be handled by the ORM layer.

If you are using Hibernate (other ORMs are available) then I would delegate to that.

If you have your own home spun ORM layer you can do whatever you want, but as weight to your arguments I would say:

1. The service should only know the pagination it wants.
2. How this is implemented should sit below the service.

Comment: I'm not using an ORM, I edited the post to add that detail. That said, the answer doesn't really solve the "who should do what" question. Simple case: given a list of objects with a `boolean` and a `Date` in the DB. I want to set the `SYSDATE()` to all objects that have the boolean to `true`. Should it be full DAO with a query or should the DAO retrieve the objects, the service edit them and then the DAO update them?

Comment: It depends.  If you want to avoid working with lots of fiddly SQL statements then pull up the data and manipulate it at the Java object level.  If you are happy working with SQL then just fire an SQL 'update where' statement into the DB.  From your 'without multiplying the database queries' is suspect you want the former.